# android beanutil.copyproperties not working in dalvik

Tags: java, android, javabeans, apache-commons-beanutils

I´ve been trying to add Apache Bean Utils into an Android Project in order to use **Beanutil.copyproperties**. Adding it through Gradle is easy and the project compile straight forward. However I´ve realised that once I make a call to **Beanutils.copyProperties** in runtime, it seems that Dalvik do not have the same java.beans as JDK do then it crash immediately.

Are there any way to solve these issues with java.bean classes? 
are there any alternatives to **Beanutils.copyProperties**?

Thanks

Comment: "are there any alternatives to Beanutils.copyProperties?" -- write a copy constructor on the class.

Comment: Thank you for this reminder. There was a copy constructor... :-)